# Android Mjpeg Viwer(IP cam) by Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, ip-camera, mjpeg

I want to view a mjpeg (IP cam) on Fragment page,
use the code as : https://bitbucket.org/neuralassembly/simplemjpegview

When it in activity is great,
then I change it into a Fragment that I can slide it left and right,
I move the onCreat() to onCreaView() and made some modify.
But when I call the DoRead().execute(URL); , the app just shutdown,

It seems in public class DoRead extends AsyncTask (String, Void, MjpegInputStream)

```
return new MjpegInputStream(res.getEntity().getContent());
```

will cause some problem, can someone help me?

```
public class MjpegActivity extends Fragment {
private static final boolean DEBUG=false;
private static final String TAG = "MJPEG";

private LinearLayout        llLayout;
private FragmentActivity    faActivity;    

private MjpegView mv = null;
String URL;

// for settings (network and resolution)
private static final int REQUEST_SETTINGS = 0;

private int width = 320 ;
private int height = 240 ;

private int ip_ad1 = 192;
private int ip_ad2 = 168;
private int ip_ad3 = 2;
private int ip_ad4 = 112;
private int ip_port = 8080;
private String ip_command = "videofeed";

private boolean suspending = false;

final Handler handler = new Handler();


public static MjpegActivity newInstance(Context context) {
    MjpegActivity fragmentFirst = new MjpegActivity();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
    return fragmentFirst;
}


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

public View  onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    faActivity  = (FragmentActivity)    super.getActivity();
    llLayout    = (LinearLayout)    inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mjpegviwer, container, false);


    SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("SAVED_VALUES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    width = preferences.getInt("width", width);
    height = preferences.getInt("height", height);
    ip_ad1 = preferences.getInt("ip_ad1", ip_ad1);
    ip_ad2 = preferences.getInt("ip_ad2", ip_ad2);
    ip_ad3 = preferences.getInt("ip_ad3", ip_ad3);
    ip_ad4 = preferences.getInt("ip_ad4", ip_ad4);
    ip_port = preferences.getInt("ip_port", ip_port);
    ip_command = preferences.getString("ip_command", ip_command);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String s_http = "http://";
    String s_dot = ".";
    String s_colon = ":";
    String s_slash = "/";
    sb.append(s_http);
    sb.append(ip_ad1);
    sb.append(s_dot);
    sb.append(ip_ad2);
    sb.append(s_dot);
    sb.append(ip_ad3);
    sb.append(s_dot);
    sb.append(ip_ad4);
    sb.append(s_colon);
    sb.append(ip_port);
    sb.append(s_slash);
    sb.append(ip_command);
    URL = new String(sb);

    mv = (MjpegView) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.mv);  
    if(mv != null){
        mv.setResolution(width, height);
    }

    super.getActivity().setTitle(R.string.title_connecting);
    new DoRead().execute(URL);
    return llLayout;
}

public void onResume() {
    if(DEBUG) Log.d(TAG,"onResume()");
    super.onResume();
    if(mv!=null){
        if(suspending){
            new DoRead().execute(URL);
            suspending = false;
        }
    }

}

public void onStart() {
    if(DEBUG) Log.d(TAG,"onStart()");
    super.onStart();
}
public void onPause() {
    if(DEBUG) Log.d(TAG,"onPause()");
    super.onPause();
    if(mv!=null){
        if(mv.isStreaming()){
            mv.stopPlayback();
            suspending = true;
        }
    }
}
public void onStop() {
    if(DEBUG) Log.d(TAG,"onStop()");
    super.onStop();
}

public void onDestroy() {
    if(DEBUG) Log.d(TAG,"onDestroy()");

    if(mv!=null){
        mv.freeCameraMemory();
    }

    super.onDestroy();
}



public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_SETTINGS:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                width = data.getIntExtra("width", width);
                height = data.getIntExtra("height", height);
                ip_ad1 = data.getIntExtra("ip_ad1", ip_ad1);
                ip_ad2 = data.getIntExtra("ip_ad2", ip_ad2);
                ip_ad3 = data.getIntExtra("ip_ad3", ip_ad3);
                ip_ad4 = data.getIntExtra("ip_ad4", ip_ad4);
                ip_port = data.getIntExtra("ip_port", ip_port);
                ip_command = data.getStringExtra("ip_command");

                if(mv!=null){
                    mv.setResolution(width, height);
                }
                SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("SAVED_VALUES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("width", width);
                editor.putInt("height", height);
                editor.putInt("ip_ad1", ip_ad1);
                editor.putInt("ip_ad2", ip_ad2);
                editor.putInt("ip_ad3", ip_ad3);
                editor.putInt("ip_ad4", ip_ad4);
                editor.putInt("ip_port", ip_port);
                editor.putString("ip_command", ip_command);

                editor.commit();

                new RestartApp().execute();
            }
            break;
    }
}

public void setImageError(){
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getActivity().setTitle(R.string.title_imageerror);
            return;
        }
    });
}

public class DoRead extends AsyncTask<String, Void, MjpegInputStream> {
    protected MjpegInputStream doInBackground(String... url) {
        //TODO: if camera has authentication deal with it and don't just not work
        HttpResponse res = null;         
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
        HttpParams httpParams = httpclient.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 5*1000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 5*1000);
        if(DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "1. Sending http request");
        try {
            res = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URI.create(url[0])));
            if(DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "2. Request finished, status = " + res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            if(res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==401){
                //You must turn off camera User Access Control before this will work
                return null;
            }
            return new MjpegInputStream(res.getEntity().getContent());  
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            if(DEBUG){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAG, "Request failed-ClientProtocolException", e);
            }
            //Error connecting to camera
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if(DEBUG){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAG, "Request failed-IOException", e);
            }
            //Error connecting to camera
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(MjpegInputStream result) {
        mv.setSource(result);
        if(result!=null){
            result.setSkip(1);
            getActivity().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }else{
            getActivity().setTitle(R.string.title_disconnected);
        }
        mv.setDisplayMode(MjpegView.SIZE_BEST_FIT);
        mv.showFps(false);
    }
}

public class RestartApp extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... v) {
        //MjpegActivity.this.finish();
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        //startActivity((new Intent(MjpegActivity.this, MjpegActivity.class)));
    }
}
}
```

The log cat get these:
04-07 04:29:42.199: DEBUG/MJPEG(4462): onStart()

04-07 04:29:42.199: DEBUG/MJPEG(4462): onResume()

04-07 04:29:42.203: DEBUG/MJPEG(4462): 1. Sending http request

04-07 04:29:42.391: DEBUG/MJPEG(4462): 2. Request finished, status = 200

04-07 04:29:42.464: DEBUG/MJPEG(4462): onPause()

04-07 04:29:43.213: DEBUG/MJPEG(4462): onStop()

04-07 04:29:43.224: DEBUG/MJPEG(4462): onDestroy()

Comment: post your logcat please

Comment: OK, I'll try to get the debug information

Comment: 04-07 04:29:42.199: DEBUG/MJPEG(4462): onStart()

04-07 04:29:42.199: DEBUG/MJPEG(4462): onResume()

04-07 04:29:42.203: DEBUG/MJPEG(4462): 1. Sending http request
04-07 04:29:42.391: DEBUG/MJPEG(4462): 2. Request finished, status = 200
04-07 04:29:42.464: DEBUG/MJPEG(4462): onPause()
04-07 04:29:43.213: DEBUG/MJPEG(4462): onStop()
04-07 04:29:43.224: DEBUG/MJPEG(4462): onDestroy()